# Text in Google maps displayed as blocks in Chrome

Tags: google-maps, ubuntu, text, 64bit, chrome

Any idea why this is happening in Google maps while using Chrome? I can see the text display but then the text changes to blocks when it finishes rendering.

I'm using Chrome Version 54.0.2840.90 (64-bit) in Ubuntu 14.04

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It may be a bug as mentioned here in this forum [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/840068/google-chrome-does-not-display-google-maps-labels-correctly/840151) or [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/VXoAbUygYdM)

You may want to do as recommended in the post, use an alternate Chrome version in Ubuntu 16.04 and report the bug like [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list)

Good Luck